# Does angular-strap select and datepicker support i18n?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

I have a angular-strap select defined as follows :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="idMedecin"
        ng-options="medecin.id as medecin.titre+' '+ medecin.prenom+' '+medecin.nom for medecin in model.medecins"
        data-placeholder="{{model.placeholder}}" bs-select>
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

In the controller, I change the value of [model.placeholder] whenever the user picks another language (i18n), by example from [Choisissez un médecin] to [Choose a doctor]. Nevertheless, this change doesn't appear on the select button.

How can I propagate to the select button, the change that was done on the model ?

I have exactly the same question for the angular-strap datepicker :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.jour" class="form-control btn-warning"
           data-min-date="today"
           data-date-format="fullDate"
           data-autoclose="true"
           data-date-type="number"
           data-use-native="true"
           bs-datepicker/>
```

When showed the first time, this component uses correctly the current language. When the user changes this language, I change [$locale.id] with the new locale. Nevertheless the datepicker is not refreshed with a new calendar.